# Error using mantisbt REST API

Tags: rest, iis, mantis

I'm using Mantis 2.11.1 on a Windows Server with IIS 8.5 and php Version 7.0.21. I have enabled the REST API ($g_webservice_rest_enabled = ON;), created an api-token and tested the API using Postman.

For the call http://srvmantis.polymania.com/mantisbt/api/rest/Issues with the header Authorization:myAPIKey I get '404 - File or directory not found' as result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I've solved it this way:
first install/enable URL Rewrite in IIS if you don't already have it
then put this in the web.config of Mantis in the system.webServer section:

```html
<rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="redirect to api" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
                      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="api/rest/index.php/{R:1}" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

hope this helps

bye
Cristian

Comment: Hello Cristian, your solution works for me. Thanxs Andreas

Comment: adding `/index.php` is working indeed: `/api/rest/index.php/issues/1234`